# What is this type of function called?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I'll start with an example. Let $f(x) = ||x||_2^2$ be the two norm function squared: so it takes in a vector $x$, and outputs the real number $\sum_i x_i^2$.

That function has the following property, if $x = (y,z)$, then $f(x) = f(y) + f(z)$. So no matter how I split up $x$ into the concatenation of several vectors, the function acts by just adding up the values on each of the components.

Is there a name for this property? I am thinking of calling it 'sum-separable function' but I wanted to know if there is already a name.

Thank you

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? If $x = (y, z)$ then $x$ and $y$ (and $x$ and $z$) are not in the same vector space, so how can you apply $f$ to $x$ and to $y$?

Comment: The function $f$ takes in *vectors* $\mathrm{x}$ and you have given it *scalars* $x_1,x_2$. The equation as written doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're just describing the associative property of addition. Let $x = (1, 2, 3, 4)$, then $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = (1^2) + (2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2) = (1^2 + 2^2) + (3^2 + 4^2) = (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2) + (4^2)$. Do you have an example of a function with this property that isn't itself a sum?

Comment: @RobArthan The function can be applied to any finite-dimensional vector space. Just like the norm

Comment: @K.defaoite No y and z aren't scalars. They are two vectors whose concatenation gives x

Comment: The notation $\|\cdot\|$ for a norm is used by convention for the norm functions on different spaces. That doesn't mean we think of  $\|\cdot\|$ as a single function that can be applied to elements of any normed space. I think you need to provide some more information about the context in which you have a function whose domain includes a class of vector spaces.

Comment: @RobArthan Ok. I get what you are saying and technically you are right. If I wanted to be formal, I would apply f to (x,0,0,0, ... 0) i.e. append a bunch of zeroes to $x$ so that it lives in the domain of $f$. (I still feel that the comments here are being too pedantic and not focusing on the heart of the question. Again for example, with the norm $|| \cdot ||$, no one complains if you apply it to vectors in different spaces.)

Comment: The problem with abuses of notation is that some are so familiar that we hardly think of them, but unexplained and unfamiliar ones are very distracting. In any case, on the understanding that you are arranging for $x$, $y$ and $z$ all to live in the domain of $f$, I would say $f$ is "additive" or maybe "additive on blah-blah-blah pairs of vectors" where "blah-blah-blah" characterises the pairs of vectors like $y$ and $z$.